# com.google.gms.google-services not adding class GoogleSignInOptions

Tags: java, android, gradle

It is very simple and the problem might be fundimental

i want to use GoogleSignInOptions, GoogleSignInResult, and Auth to implement google+ signin.

i am following the guides here are the gradle builds:

project build:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://jzaccone.github.io/SlidingMenu-aar" }
    }
}
```

app build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ili.BDigital"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':eventBrowser')
}
```

library (extra module) build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub:3.7.5'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.wefika:horizontal-picker:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'



    compile files('libs/com.haarman.listviewanimations-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/htmlcleaner-2.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/socialauth-4.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/socialauth-android-3.2.jar')

}





/*
compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android-debug:3.7.+'
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1@jar'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:4.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0'
compile 'com.github.pedrovgs:renderers:1.0.9'
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-rc1'

 */
```

I've been stuck on this for a day and it's driving me insane

UPDATE:  I removed "compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')" and now even R is giving me "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: Looks like an error is not letting it build

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line in the bottom of your build.gradle file (which you import your dependency)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: it has no effect where i add it. i tried adding it both under apply plugin: 'com.android.library' and at the end of the file. It had no effect